# Sequelize concat two columns

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, npm, sequelize.js

```sql
SELECT "Apple"."id", "Final"."id"
FROM "Apple"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Camel" ON "Apple"."id" = "Camel"."apple_id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Dad" ON "Camel"."id" = "Dad"."camel_id"
INNER JOIN "Final" ON "Camel"."final_id" = "Final"."id" OR "Dad"."final_id" = "Final"."id";
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve. I have a column `Apple` which is referenced by 2 columns `Camel` and `Dad` which reference column `Final` but only one of `Camel` or `Dad` with hold a reference in a row. So I'm joining in the last sql line against both columns. Is this possible in sequelize

```
Apple.findAll({
  include: [
    {model: Camel, include: [Final]},
    {model: Dad,   include: [Final]},
  ],
});
```

This is a sample of what the query currently looks like. I have tried adding `required: true` to both inner includes and with the `Final` includes. I tried adding `right: true` Both did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [raw sql](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/raw-queries/) is not an option, you can try with `include[].on` option - should work as `where` option.

1. Raw sql:

```
const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query("UPDATE users SET y = 42 WHERE x = 12");
```

2. include[].on option:

```
const { Op } = require("sequelize");

Apple.findAll({
  include: [
    {model: Camel},
    {model: Dad},
    {
      model: Final,
      required: true,
      on: { 
        '$Final.id$': {
          [Op.or]: [ Sequelize.col('Camel.final_id'), Sequelize.col('Dad.final_id') ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
});
```

Comment: I had to change `Apple` to have a `BelongsToMany` relationship with `Final` through `Dad` and `Camel` but it worked. Thanks